# What product can you use to zoom and focus cursors when screencasting--what's the best screencast software?

Tags: images, marketing

I've tried iShowU to do screencasts, but the software does not allow you to zoom in and focus on where your cursor is point.

What is the best software for MacOS that allows you to do simple effects like zooming when screencasting?

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with marketing or images and should be on Superuser.

Comment: I agree. Closing as off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/).